# State and Country select show most used with city-state gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, rubygems

I use city-state gem to populate Country and State dropdown, in order to save address information. 
I would like to know if there a way to push "the most used/selected" states to the top of the list.

I would want to show them first by "the most selected states", and then by all states in alphabetical order?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The main list you are sending to the dropdown is an `Array`? The most popular list is an `Array`? Reject elements included in populars then `unshift` to main list. However, better you add some code to the question, to give a more precise suggestion.

Comment: @iGian The gem returns a hash and im not sure ruby hashes actually have an order.

Answer (score 1):

No, gem currently does not have that kind of filtering.
There is only an info about showing last country:

```
When getting a city list, you can also specifies the country:

CS.cities(:sp, :br)

The country is an optional argument. city-state always uses the last country that you used.
```

https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state

Of course you can upgrade the gem by adding field for counting most used countries/cities ...